# [_LSDefaults sharedInstance]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1f36e3dd8

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ipados

I updated my `ipad` to `ipad OS` and it ran successfully for about 15 seconds, then crashed.

**Crash info :**

> [_LSDefaults sharedInstance]: unrecognized selector sent to class
>   0x1f36e3dd8

Apple BUG? this class is in `<CoreServices/CoreServices.h>`

Comment: Without providing your code, it is unlikely anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: I get this in iOS 13 too. Also print: invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 3):

Do you use the UMCCommon or UMCAnalytics?
This seems to the UMCCommon Component Bug in iOS13。 I have update to the UMCCommon 2.1.1，It disappeared.